# find the date y ( probably we have 1000 files 999 have date x and 1 have y date ) and the corresponding file?

Tags: c#, dictionary

**Please suggest the simplest way to do the below logic.
we can use data-tables and query from the table?**

```
string[] filePath = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.txt",SearchOption.AllDirectories);

Dictionary<string, DateTime> dic = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();
foreach (string CurrentPath in filePath)
  {
      string Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@CurrentPath);

      string loadedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Content.Substring(9,8), "yyyyMMdd",
                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
      DateTime Datevalue = DateTime.Parse(loadedDate);

      String FileName = Path.GetFileName(CurrentPath);
     dic.Add(Path.GetFileName(CurrentPath), Datevalue);
   }
```

Description:

filepath contains the list of .txt file path
  Inside the foreach loop reading all the file content and found the date present in the content.

Added all the date valueand the FileName in a Dictionary.

Now i need to find the date which is different and the corresponding filename.
  For EG: we have 3 files File1.txt, File2.txt,File3.txt. first 2 files having the date value 25/9/2019 
  and the 3rd file having the date value 24/9/2019.
  here we need to find the date which is different from the other i.e 24/9/2019 and the corresponding 
  file name File3.txt.

From the dictionary value how can i find the date(date which is different from the other date) and the corresponding file name?.

please suggest the simplest or any-other way to do this logic.

Comment: How can i find the date which is different from other dates and the corresponding file from the dictionary value.

Comment: If there's 10 files with all different dates. Which one is the one that is different from "other dates"?

Comment: What if out of those 10 files, 2 have date X, 3 have date Y, 2 have date Z and then the rest have different dates?

Comment: Hi James  Maximum possibility is 2. if we have 1000 files probably 999 have date x and the remaining 1 file have y date.

Comment: You can use LINQ `GroupBy` to group the KeyValue pairs by their Value component. Now you can look at the group counts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **Dictionary** to have a key-value pairs of text files and the extracted dates from them.

```
string directory = @"C:\";
string[] filePath = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
Dictionary<string, DateTime> dic = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();

foreach (string CurrentPath in filePath)
{
    string Content = File.ReadAllText(@CurrentPath);
    string loadedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Content.Substring(9, 8), "yyyyMMdd",
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
    DateTime Datevalue = DateTime.Parse(loadedDate);

    dic.Add(Path.GetFileName(CurrentPath), Datevalue);
}
```

**Edit**

For example, you could add to the dictionary only the distinct dates with their text files. Please refactor the code and try:

```
string directory = @"C:\";
string[] filePath = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
Dictionary<DateTime, string> dic = new Dictionary<DateTime, string>();
foreach (string CurrentPath in filePath)
{
    string Content = File.ReadAllText(@CurrentPath);
    string loadedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Content.Substring(9, 8), "yyyyMMdd",
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
    DateTime Datevalue = DateTime.Parse(loadedDate);

    if(!dic.ContainsKey(Datevalue))
        dic.Add(Datevalue, Path.GetFileName(CurrentPath));
}
```

Then you can check if the dictionary contains more than one entry which means that you have two or more different dates that you can do whatever you want accordingly.

```
if (dic.Count > 1)
{ /* You have different dates connected to their files. */ }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you JQSOFT. Sure i can use dictionary to have a key-value pairs. But how can i find the date which is different from other and the corresponding file from the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You can use a helper dictionary with number of occurrences for each date. The method that returns you the fileName, would be like:

```
 public string GetFileName()
 {
     Dictionary<DateTime, int> dts = new Dictionary<DateTime, int>();
     foreach (KeyValuePair<string, DateTime> item in dic)
     {
        if (dts.ContainsKey(item.Value))
        {
          dts[item.Value]++;
        }
        else
        {
          dts.Add(item.Value, 1);
        }
     }

     var value = dts.Where(x => x.Value == 1).Select(x => x.Key).FirstOrDefault();
     foreach (KeyValuePair<string, DateTime> item in dic)
     {
        if (item.Value == value)
        {
           return item.Key;
        }
      }
      return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is ambiguous as there is no way to tell which is the right date. However if you want to find a list of dates and the files associated with those dates you can improve your code by making the date as the key.

So your dictionary declaration can change to -

```
Dictionary<DateTime, List<string>> dic = new Dictionary<DateTime, List<string>>();
```

Then we can perform lookup on the keys in the dictionary. So you can change this `dic.Add(Path.GetFileName(CurrentPath), Datevalue);` by a method call like

```
AddFileName(dic,Path.GetFileName(CurrentPath), Datevalue);

void AddFileName(Dictionary<DateTime, List<string>> fileInfo, DateTime dt, string fileName)
        {
            if (fileInfo.ContainsKey(dt))
            {
                var fileList = fileInfo[dt];
                fileList.Add(fileName);
            }
            else
            {
                fileInfo.Add(dt, new List<string> { fileName });
            }
        }
```

And now you have the unique dates and the associated file list to perform the next steps...

Comment: Maximum possibility is 2. if we have 1000 files probably 999 have date x and the remaining 1 file have y date.

Comment: Ok, then the you can iterate the keys and get the different dates and the list of associated files.